# Why does my Objective-C dot accessor behaves differently with an implicit getter?

Tags: objective-c, getter, accessor

In the following code, I get '(null)' for the second line in the output but not the fourth.

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSString *foo;
@property (getter=getBar, readonly) NSString *bar;
@end
```

**main.m**

```
@implementation MyClass
- (NSString *)getFoo { return @"foo"; }
- (NSString *)getBar { return @"bar"; }
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {     
        MyClass *myClassInstance = [MyClass new];

        NSLog(@"%@", myClassInstance.getFoo);
        NSLog(@"%@", myClassInstance.foo);

        NSLog(@"%@", myClassInstance.getBar);
        NSLog(@"%@", myClassInstance.bar);
    }
    return 0;
```

**output**

```
foo
(null)
bar
bar
```

Why am I seeing this?

Comment: I should have said, I'm using Xcode version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Objective C getters are just the name of the property; `foo` in the `foo` case. In this, there's no relationship between `getFoo` and `foo`, so you access the underlying property via its normal getter. It's never been set, so it's `nil`, which logs as `null`.

In the later case, you establish the getter for `bar` as `getBar`. Thus, accessing `bar` the property evaluates the getter function you specified.

Comment: And here is the documentation that reiterates what Adam says:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html